# how do i set the text of a TextView to an object's integer value thats in another class

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listView that uses an Adapter that i created myself. When the first row of the listView is pressed I have made it so it creates a new object from class called Ship that has 3 integer values. Below

```
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.hangar);

        ListAdapter adapter = new HangarAdapter(this, ship);
            hangarList.setAdapter(adapter);

            hangarList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                   Intent sendListEvents = new Intent();
                    if(position == 0)
                    {
                        Ship ship1 = new Ship();
                        ship1.setAddAmount(50);
                        ship1.setAddTime(5000);
                        ship1.setAddSpend(1000);
                        ship1.shipAdd();
                    }
}
}
```

In my adapter i have a textView called TextView2 and I want to set the text of it to ship1's value called addSpend. How do i do that.

```
    if (position == 0) {
                theImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.planet);
                TextView2.setText("This is where I want ship1's addSpend value to be displayed")
}
```

Comment: Can someone please help me here

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to pass the integer value from one class to another and then you can use `YourTextView.setText(YOUR_VARIABLE)` to change the value of the TextView.

To pass values from one class to another, you can check out these tutorials: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) and [here](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~dianeh/tutorials/params/).

Comment: how do i do that then?

Comment: could you explain your answer so i know how to pass the integer value

Comment: You can check out these tutorials on how to pass values between classes: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) and [here](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~dianeh/tutorials/params/)